# Trying to add foreign key results in "ERROR 1064 at line 1"

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys, create-table

I'm trying to create a foreign key in the `name`, `address_id`, and `phone` column but I keep getting an error.

```
mysql> create table driver(driver_id int(64) not null primary key,name varchar(100) not null,phone varchar(20) not null);

mysql> describe driver;
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| driver_id | int(64)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name      | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| phone     | varchar(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> create table customer(customer_id int(10) not null,name varchar(100) not null,age int(5) not null,address_id int(64) not null,phone varchar(20) not null,primary key(customer_id),foreign key(name) references driver(name);
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Does any of the tables contains some data before the two are created ?

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is that both the parent and children column must have the same datatype *and length*. So you would need to align the length of the `name` column in the child table with the parent table (or the other way around): as of now, on is is `varchar(100)` and the other is `varchar(50)`.

But even so, the foreign key does not look good from a design perspective: why would you want to reference the driver `name`? Although MySQL would allow that (provided that you create an index on the parent column), this does not allow a customer to uniquely identify a driver, which questions the relevance of the foreign key. I would recommend referencing the primary key instead:

```
create table customer(
    customer_id int(10) not null,
    driver_id int not null,
    age int(5) not null,
    address_id int(64) not null,
    phone varchar(20) not null,
    primary key(customer_id),
    foreign key(driver_id) references driver(driver_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL error is

> There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns near 'foreign key(name) references driver(name))'

You need to add an index to the 'name' column.

```
CREATE TABLE `driver` (
    `driver_id` int(64) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     KEY `name` (`name`)
);

create table customer(
    customer_id int(10) not null,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    age int(5) not null,
    address_id int(64) not null,
    phone varchar(20) not null,
    primary key(customer_id),
    foreign key(name) references driver(name)
);
```

Comment: ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem (1064) --  It says `near ''`, which means `at the end`.  Check your parentheses.  The closing one for the `CREATE` is missing.